# How to uncheck checkboxes when check other one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have four checkboxes.Initially all are checked. When I click the none checkbox the other checkboxes are unchecked.

**html**

```
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='a' class="example"  value='1000' checked/>A</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='b' class="example" value='1000' class='termcls'checked />B</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='c' class="example" value='1000' checked/>C</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='none' onchange="uncheckOthers()" value='0' class='termcls'/>(None)</label>
```

**jQuery**

```
 function uncheckOthers()
 {
    $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
 }
```

Comment: Just `$('input.example').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: `this` is not _this-the `None` checkbox_ inside the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by the [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar), `this` refers to the `window` in `uncheckOthers` not to the `None` check-box element.

If you are invoking inline function and expecting current element as `this` in hadler, pass `this` as argument.

Try this:

```js
 function uncheckOthers(elem) {
   $('input.example').not(elem).prop('checked', !elem.checked);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='a' class="example" value='1' checked/>A</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='b' class="example" value='2' class='termcls' checked />B</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='c' class="example" value='3' checked/>C</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='none' onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" value='0' class='termcls' />(None)</label>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9u32ecko/)

Comment: HOw can i take the sum of these three checkbox value

Comment: Listen `onchange` event of the `checkbox`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


    });
    function uncheckOthers() {
        $('input.example').prop('checked', false);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='a' class="example"  value='1' checked/>A</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='b' class="example" value='2' class='termcls'checked />B</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='c' class="example" value='3' checked/>C</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='none' onchange="uncheckOthers()" value='0' class='termcls'/>(None)</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer above I did a function to uncheck  the none checkbox if one of anothers checkbox is checked.

```js
 function uncheckOthers(elem) {
   $('input.example').not(elem).prop('checked', !elem.checked);
 }

 function uncheckNone(elem) {
   if(elem.checked)
   {
     $('input.termcls').prop('checked', false);
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='a' onchange="uncheckNone(this)" class="example" value='1' checked/>A</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='b' onchange="uncheckNone(this)" class="example" value='2' class='termcls' checked />B</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='c' onchange="uncheckNone(this)" class="example" value='3' checked/>C</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='none' onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" value='0' class='termcls' />(None)</label>
```